# Which button was pressed?

Tags: html, forms, jstl

I know this question has likely been asked before, but I cannot seem to find a reasonable answer to it for my circumstances.

I have a form with multiple buttons in it that submit and I am required to know which button was pressed.

a small code snippet of the inside of the form may look like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="<fmt:message key="ID001"/>"/> <!-- Save -->  
<input type="submit" name="action" value="<fmt:message key="ID002"/>"/> <!-- Delete --> 
<input type="submit" name="action" value="<fmt:message key="ID003"/>"/> <!-- some other action -->
```

The fmt:message part simply takes into consideration the language of the client and places the word on the button.

Until now, I was adding an action handler on the submit buttons and adding a hidden input element onto the form telling me which one was pressed, but I need to support the site without depending on javascript.

Since the values of the buttons are variable, how can I approach this? (Essentially I can do this if input had a place to say value="" and text="", but it doesn't)

I thought about moving the "values" that I want such as "save" and "delete" to the name attribute, and checking whether or not the value is set by doing something like the following:

```
<c:if test="${!empty param.save}">
.
.
.
</c:if>
```

However, the problem arises when I have,say a list of x size that can each be deleted.
I'll give you an example of what I mean:

form jsp:

```
<input type="submit" name="delete_row|1" value="<fmt:message key="ID001"/>"/> <!-- delete first row-->  
<input type="submit" name="delete_row|2" value="<fmt:message key="ID002"/>"/> <!-- deleted second row --> 
<input type="submit" name="delete_row|3" value="<fmt:message key="ID003"/>"/> <!-- delete third row -->
...
```

server side jsp:

```
<c:if test="${!empty param.delete_row|x}"> 
.
. <%-- handle the specific row deletion here--%>
.
</c:if>
```

^- I have no idea what that x is going to be... it can be 1, or 100 or even more, so I would need a way to find any param that starts with delete_row and delimit it somehow.

I've looked a little into it and found the `<button>` element, however it is not supported in some versions of IE (IE<8 as far as I can remember?).

So, my restrictions are:

- no js
- must be supported by browsers as old as IE6 or preferably even more

Anyone have any suggestions?
Please comment if I need to explain something in more detail,

Answer (score 0):

Use `button` instead of `input`:

```
<button name='submit' type='submit' value='1'><fmt:message key="ID001"/></button>
<button name='submit' type='submit' value='2'><fmt:message key="ID002"/></button>
<button name='submit' type='submit' value='3'><fmt:message key="ID003"/></button>
```

And if you want to have click-able button, but don't submit form, add `type='button'` to it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Justinas. My concern is that the <button> element is not supported by older versions of IE, which was why I was asking this question to find another way around it. I may end up having to talk to my boss about it, but as far as I know a large amount of people still use very old versions of IE and I therefore have to support it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, and hope someone would correct me if I'm wrong, HTML specs does not provide what you're looking for in case of using . Which, by the way,would recommend that you look in the HTML4 specs.

So, either you don't support older browsers, or use Java script.
In both cases, you'll need to talk to your boss.